# Can't import button in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, button

I need some help with importing the `button` in `react`, I am totally new to react

I have created one `table` where I am displaying the `data` through `JSON` and now I want to add one `button` below the table, when the user clicks on it, it will redirect to a new page
I have `imported` the Button in my js file

```
import { Button } from 'react-native';
```

I have used `Button` in the render HTML as

```
<Button variant="primary">Primary</Button>
```

**Code snippet**

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Table } from 'react-bootstrap';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import '../scss/components/table';
import data from '../../public/userData';

export default function ReservedListView() {
  console.log('data :' + JSON.stringify(data));
  let header = Object.keys(data[0]);
  console.log('header :' + header);
  return (
    <div>
      <table id="students" class="table">
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Day</th>
            <th>SimeSlot</th>
          </tr>
          {data.map((el, index) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{el.name}</td>
              <td>{el.date}</td>
              <td>{el.day}</td>
              <td>{el.timeSlot}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <Button variant="primary">Primary</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**I am getting this error when I import the button**
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are developing in React but you want to Import a Button from react-native?

Can you not just use the normal button in React?

https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

Comment: I have tried this way at that time it was not working but now its working fine

Comment: is there any specific reason for its not working with import? is it because I was trying to import it from react-native?

Comment: @Priya yes you are trying to use components from react-native in a react project which is not possible

Comment: ok, got it Thank You! for the clarification :)

Comment: @Priya No worries - consider to accept my answer if everything is clarified for you :) Good Luck and have a good Day!